# How to convert the model with grid_sample to TensorRT with INT8 quantization?

Tags: pytorch, onnx, quantization, tensorrt

I am trying to convert the model with torch.nn.functional.grid_sample from Pytorch (1.9) to TensorRT (7) with INT8 quantization throught ONNX (opset 11).
Opset 11 does not support grid_sample conversion to ONNX. Thus I used ONNX graphsurgeon together with the external GridSamplePlugin as it is [proposed here](https://github.com/TrojanXu/onnxparser-trt-plugin-sample). With it the conversion to TensorRT (both with and without INT8 quantization) is succesfull.
Pytorch and TRT model without INT8 quantization provide results close to identical ones (MSE is of e-10 order). But for TensorRT with INT8 quantization MSE is much higher (185).

grid_sample operator gets two inputs: the input signal and the sampling grid. Both of them should be of the same type. In the GridSamplePlugin only processing of kFLOAT and kHALF is implemented.
In my case X coordinate in the absolute sampling grid (before it is converted to the relative one required for grid_sample) is changing in the range [-d; W+d], and [-d; H+d] for Y coordinate. Maximal value of W is 640, and 360 for H. And the coordinates may have non-integer values in this range.
For the test purposes I created the test model that contains only grid_sample layer. And in this case TensorRT results with and without INT8 quantization are identical.

Here is the code of the test model:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2

BATCH_SIZE = 1
WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 360

def calculate_grid(B, H, W, dtype, device='cuda'):
    xx = torch.arange(0, W, device=device).view(1, -1).repeat(H, 1).type(dtype)
    yy = torch.arange(0, H, device=device).view(-1, 1).repeat(1, W).type(dtype)
    xx = xx + yy * 0.25
    if B > 1:
        xx = xx.view(1, 1, H, W).repeat(B, 1, 1, 1)
        yy = yy.view(1, 1, H, W).repeat(B, 1, 1, 1)
    else:
        xx = xx.view(1, 1, H, W)
        yy = yy.view(1, 1, H, W)
    vgrid = torch.cat((xx, yy), 1).type(dtype)
    return vgrid.type(dtype)

def modify_grid(vgrid, H, W):
    vgrid = torch.cat([
        torch.sub(2.0 * vgrid[:, :1, :, :].clone() / max(W - 1, 1), 1.0),
        torch.sub(2.0 * vgrid[:, 1:2, :, :].clone() / max(H - 1, 1), 1.0),
        vgrid[:, 2:, :, :]], dim=1)
    vgrid = vgrid.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
    return vgrid

class GridSamplingBlock(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GridSamplingBlock, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, input, vgrid):
        output = torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(input, vgrid)
        return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(GridSamplingBlock())
    model.cuda()
    print("Reading inputs")
    img = cv2.imread("result/left_frame_rect_0373.png")
    img = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    img_in = torch.from_numpy(img.astype(float)).view(1, 1, HEIGHT, WIDTH).cuda()
    vgrid = calculate_grid(BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT, WIDTH, img_in.dtype)
    vgrid = modify_grid(vgrid, HEIGHT, WIDTH)
    np.save("result/grid", vgrid.cpu().detach().numpy())
    print("Getting output")
    with torch.no_grad():
        model.module.eval()
        img_out = model.module(img_in, vgrid)
        img = img_out.cpu().detach().numpy().squeeze()
        cv2.imwrite("result/grid_sample_test_output.png", img.astype(np.uint8))
```

Saved grid is used for both calibration and inference of the TensorRT model.

So the questions are:

- Is it valid to apply INT8 quantization to functions with at least one
  indexing input (like grid_sample)? Doesn't such quantization lead to
  significant change of the result (if we apply INT8 quantization to
  the input with the range [0..640) for example)?
- How INT8 quantization works with the custom plugin, if only FP32 and FP16 are implemented in this plugin code?
- Is the same result of the test network in TensorRT with and without INT8 quantization obtained due to the fact that the grid_sample input is actually the network input?

My environment:

- TensorRT Version: 7
- GPU Type: NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Nvidia Driver Version: 470.63.01
- CUDA Version: 10.2.89
- CUDNN Version: 8.1.1
- Operating System + Version: Ubuntu 18.04
- Python Version (if    applicable): 3.7
- PyTorch Version (if applicable): 1.9

Steps to reproduce:

- Run the test code to save the grid and get Torch result. Use any
  input image for test.
- Build TensorRT OSS with the custom plugin according to
  this [sample](https://github.com/TrojanXu/onnxparser-trt-plugin-sample). The latest
  version of TRT OSS requires some adaptation of GridSamplePlugin, so
  better to use the recomended TensorRT OSS version.
- Create ONNX model according to the [code example](https://github.com/TrojanXu/onnxparser-trt-plugin-sample).
- Create TensorRT engine with or without INT8 quantization and run the inference. In my C++ code I used https://github.com/llohse/libnpy for reading grid.npy file.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your model into 2 parts, one before grid sample and another after it, and do int8 quantization respectively. Having grid_sample work in INT8 will compromise your model performance greatly.
This will result in a change in your network structure so it may change the optimization of the graph.